# KERAS: How to set weights of Conv2D Layer explicitly using a tensor of same shape as required by weights?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

I want to create a conv2d layer by explicitly defining the weight matrix of the layer (Conv2D has use_bias parameter set to False). I have been trying to do this using layer.set_weights([K]) where K is (?, 7, 7, 512, 512) Tensor.

In simple Tensorflow API, it could probably be done by passing the tensor the filter parameter in tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter,..)

Moreover, I have more problem and that i show should I address the batch dimension in the K Tensor because it has been generated by a network

Basically I want to implement a hypernetwork in which i have generated the weights for the Conv2D layer specified above, from another network in the Tensor K. The weight Tensor K has shape [height, width, Filters, Channels]

```
template= Input(shape=(448,684,3))
hyper_net= VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, 
input_tensor=None, input_shape=(448,684, 3))

k1= hyper_net(template)

kconv1= hyper_net.get_layer(name='block5_conv1')
config_conv1= kconv1.get_config()
k1conv1 = Conv2D.from_config(config_conv1)(k1)

kconv2= hyper_net.get_layer(name='block5_conv2')
config_conv2= kconv2.get_config()
k1conv2 = Conv2D.from_config(config_conv2)(k1conv1)

k1pool1= MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,3))(k1conv2)

k1pool1= Reshape((7,7,512,1))(k1pool1)
print(k1pool1.shape)

K= Conv3D(512, (1,1,1), strides=(1, 1, 1), padding='valid', 
activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01))(k1pool1)


ortho= Input(tensor=tf.convert_to_tensor(O))
base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, 
input_tensor=None, input_shape=(1760, 1760, 3))

o1= base_model(ortho)

Oconv1= Conv2D(512, (7, 7), activation='relu', padding='valid',use_bias=False)
Oconv1.set_weights([K])
```

It gives error as:

```
ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "conv2d_4" with a  weight list of length 1, but the layer was expecting 0 weights. Provided weights: [<tf.Tensor 'conv3d_9/add:0' shape=(?, 7, 7, 512, ...
```

Comment: What is `?` for in K. It should be of `4` dims.

Comment: ? represents batch dimension because the K Tensor is the output of a network

Comment: You don't need batch_size while defining weights. It is of following dims `(kernel, Kernel, input_channels, output_channels)`.

Comment: Yes. That is why I'm trying to handle the batch dimension. So that the weights generated by a separate network (having batch dimension) can be changed to 
    (kernel, Kernel, input_channels, output_channels)

Answer (score 4):

In Tensorflow 2.0 with eager execution, you might be able to do 1 of the below:

1) You can call the `build` method on `Oconv1` before using the `set_weights` method. You are getting the `ValueError` as the weights Variables in the layer are not yet initialized, hence the layer cannot take in any weights via `set_weights` before building.

```
Oconv1= Conv2D(512, (7, 7), activation='relu', padding='valid',use_bias=False)
input_shape = tf.TensorShape([None, h, w, c])  # to define h, w, c based on shape of layer input
Oconv1.build(input_shape)
Oconv1.set_weights([K])
```

2) You can also pass in a `weights` kwarg into the `Conv2D` constructor.

```
Oconv1= Conv2D(512, (7, 7), activation='relu', padding='valid',use_bias=False,weights=[K])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it directly from a tensor, but you can set the weights in Keras with a numpy array. So you can convert the tensor to a numpy array and than set it:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
weights = K.eval() # Convert tensor to numpy
Oconv1.set_weights(weights) # Set weights of layer
```

Obviously, the dimensions of the tensor/numpy-array and the keras layer must be identical.

Comment: By doing as you said, it asks for a tf.placeholder object to run eval(). I can't provide the placeholder tensor as it is Input to my model which will be the training data

Comment: This is the error: InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,448,684,3]

Comment: So you don't want to initialize the weights based on some tensor, you want to update them online? based on some outer model? I think that you need to add more code to clarify...

Comment: Hey Mark, firstly i want to thank you. I have added more code. Secondly yes I want to generate weights through another model and then reshape the output to be weights for the Oconv1 layer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement recently, and the below code worked for me;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import tensorflow as tf
import requests

def plot_two_images(img1: np.array, img2: np.array):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(img1), cmap='gray')
    fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(img2), cmap='gray')
    plt.show()

def read_input():
    url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/kagglesdsdata/datasets/927555/1569529/PetImages/Cat/1.jpg?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=databundle-worker-v2%40kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20230616%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20230616T104014Z&X-Goog-Expires=345600&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=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"
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    open('cat1.jpg', 'wb').write(r.content)
    img = Image.open('cat1.jpg')
    img = ImageOps.grayscale(img)
    img = img.resize(size=(224, 224))
    return np.array(img)

def conv2D(x):
    conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 3, use_bias=False)
    input_shape = tf.TensorShape([None, 224, 224, 1])
    conv1.build(input_shape)
    weights = [tf.convert_to_tensor([
                [
                    [[0]], [[-1]], [[0]]
                ],
                [
                    [[-1]], [[5]], [[-1]]
                ],
                [
                    [[0]], [[-1]], [[0]]
                ]
              ])]
    conv1.set_weights(weights)
    return conv1(x)

def main():
    img = read_input()
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=(0, -1))
    img = tf.convert_to_tensor(img, dtype=float)
    sharpened = conv2D(img).numpy().astype('int16')
    plot_two_images(img, sharpened)
    print(sharpened.shape)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).